# Eclipse plugin development problem

Tags: eclipse, swing, swt

In my eclipse plugin project, I use swt-awt bridge to make my swing JFrame in a multipage editor. There are some buttons in this swing JFrame will create a pop up window (another JFrame). When I using debug mode like run as eclipse application, all things worked. But when I export the project to a plugin and deployed it, these buttons can not create that pupup window.

Anyone met this problem before? Thank you for help.

Comment: any exception when clicking the button?

Comment: There is no any exception when I clinking the button. It works perfect in debug mode. But when I package them to a plugin, all new JFrame can not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I had a lot of problems with SWT_AWT bridge.  Mine were mostly around flickering in my embedded swing parts.

I started using the albireo project (http://www.eclipse.org/albireo/) which resolved all of my issues.  Take a look, it may help.